# Using mod_rewrite to call in a default image URL if requested image URL is not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, centos, http-status-code-404

I'm fairly new to htaccess rewrites and wondered if anyone could offer a solution for me. So on my site I have users with custom avatar images in the following format.

http://siteurl.tld/customavatars/avatar78364_1.gif
(Where the numbers (78364_1) are the users ID)

Each user gets their own customavatars image link generated even if they dont have an image uploaded. Here is the issue, at the moment I'm using an ErrorDocument 404 /images/icons/no-avatar.png as a default image for any users without their own image uploaded. This 404 isn't good for SEO so what I want to try do is use rewrites to keep the origin URL but serv the no-avatar image file.

In effect anyone going to http://siteurl.tld/customavatars/avatarUSERID_HASNOIMAGE.gif is just shown the default image without being redirected to no-avatar.png in the browser URL.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Would a appreciate a short feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} avatar.*\.gif$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /.* http://siteurl.tld/customavatars/no-avatar.png [R=301,L]
```

Effectively any requested file that does start with avatar and ends with .gif but doesn't exist is answered with http://siteurl.tld/customavatars/no-avatar.png

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Just tried this now, works a treat. Thanks for your help!!